# how do i increase a map's allocation size in GO language?

Tags: go

I have a collection of objects that will sometime have new element added to it.

How do I increase the internal map size?

Do I need to reallocate the whole map every time the element count exceed allocated count?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Go specification says:

> A new, empty map value is made using the built-in function make, which takes the map type and an optional capacity hint as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(map[string]int) 
> make(map[string]int, 100)
> ```
>
> The initial capacity does not bound its size: maps grow to accommodate the number of items stored in them

So, no, you don't have to make any allocations to a map once you've created it. This is handled internally by the Go runtime. The optional capacity used when making the map it's only a hint, not a limitation.

Comment: oh i found that my map not yet being "make" so caused an error. no the out of space problem. but how do i call make when the container struct is create? I don't see constructor in go lang.

Comment: True, there are no constructors in Go. Instead of constructors, you can use a factory function with same name as the type, just with `New` prepended. Eg. `func NewStruct([arguments]) *Struct`. It is idiomatic to do so.